# iOS 15 has broken NSPersistentCloudKitContainer sync

Tags: ios, cloudkit, ios15

I have an existing app in the App Store that has been using an NSPersistentCloudKitContainer since iOS13 with no issues. My models are very simple, an `Article` model and a `Tags` model that is a many-to-many relationship on `Article`. Since iOS15 (I've also tried 15.1 beta) the `Tags` records are no longer downloaded, they are however uploaded when created. What happens instead is that all articles will be downloaded and all tags will be missing. Downgrading and going through the process on iOS14 I'm able to verify that this did previously work as intended - when opening the app all `Articles` and all `Tags` are downloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found a config issue in one of my Models which was somehow preventing the child relation from being imported, specifically in iOS15. I'm still not entirely sure why it was working prior to that - perhaps I'd inadvertently exploited a bug that was fixed in iOS15.